# How to change icons in the side pane of the Nautilus file browser?

Tags: nautilus, icons, appearance

Right-click in the main panel allows to change icons associated to files of directories, and this is cool for content organization and so on.

Unfortunately, right click on small directories on the side pane does not allow to change its properties (such as icon).

I try to change the original directory icon, expecting that its side pane version would change accordingly, but surprisingly, nothing appends...

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't sidebar bookmarks overlayed with their folder icons?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97118/why-arent-sidebar-bookmarks-overlayed-with-their-folder-icons)

Answer (score 5):

You currently cannot change the icons used in the places and bookmarks menus in nautilus.

This is a bug.

See [this bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/423890)

and [this bug report on GNOME bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=601709)

Comment: Those bugfixes say that they're now resolved, but I still can't see how to change the icons of my bookmarks.

Comment: Seems like it's once again impossible to change icons used in the sidebar: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/how-to-customize-bookmark-icon-in-nautilus-sidebar/12020