# Why aren't sidebar bookmarks overlayed with their folder icons?

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, icons

I'm trying to figure out why my bookmarked directories (on the left sidebar of the nautilus file browser) do not have icons. From what I've seen on random screenshots people have Down arrow for Downloads, a paper for Documents etc.

I even explicitly set an icon to Dropbox directory to have an earth symbol.
I tried enabling "Extra" effects in Visual Appearance, didn't help.

Where's the setting? What do I need to modify?

[image: Nautilus Icons]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was reported - believe or not back in 2009 as a [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/423890).

I've test this on lucid, natty and oneiric and confirm the fixed bug-report was incorporated into oneiric.  It hasn't been backported to earlier versions of Ubuntu.

There is a proposed [code patch](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/review?bug=601709&attachment=166492).

Thus - if you definitely want this in Lucid, you will need to compile a custom version of nautilus :(

I can confirm that the patch in question does work in lucid...

[image]

---

If you are interested in trying this custom version of nautilus I've created a PPA with the patch applied to the source code.

To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/nautilus
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Logout and login

Use the linked question to assign a custom icon to the folder.  When you create a bookmark for an item within the folder, the bookmark folder icon will inherit the icon of the associated folder containing the file.

---

Linked Question:

[How can I assign custom icons to folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79110/how-can-i-assign-custom-icons-to-folders)